# Как оптимизировать скрипт парсинга данных сайта на VBA?

Tags: массивы, vba

Прилагаю скрипт парсинга данных сайта. Запускается из екселя. Он свою функцию выполняет, но в процесе работы виснет и работает дольше чему нужно. (Замерял время на маленьком объеме ). Как можно оптимизировать этот скрипт используя масиввы например? Подскажите плиз массивы идут туго - не понимаю с какой стороны взять быка за рога?

```
Public Sub parse_kiev()
Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument, user_items As Object, titleElem As Object, _
detailsElem As Object, user_item As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim i As Integer
Dim strT As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim startT As Variant
Dim finishT As Variant


startT = Timer

For j = 1 To 1244
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "https://rieltor.ua/users/?page=" & j & "", False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
Set user_items = html.getElementsByClassName("user-item")

If j = 1 Then i = 1 Else: i = d

For Each user_item In user_items
Set titleElem = user_item.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("div")(5).innerText
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("div")(5).innerText
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 5).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    strT = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 6).Value = titleElem.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
    i = i + 1
    d = i
Next

Next

finishT = Timer
MsgBox "Время выполнения макроса " & (finishT - startT) / 60 & " мин."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае "бутылочным горлышком" задачи является не столько работа с COM-объектами (листы, диапазоны и т.д.), сколько следующие 2 момента:

1. Парсинг текста веб-страницы ( html.body.innerHTML = .responseText )
2. Сетевые запросы к удалённому серверу ( http.Open / http.Send )

На 1-й пункт мы повлиять особо не можем. Зато можем совладать со 2-м. Надо дополнительно подключить в диалоге "Tools->References" библиотеку "Microsoft WinHTTP Services" и задействовать возможность асинхронной работы объекта `WinHttpRequest`.

Один момент: не следует запускать слишком много асинхронных запросов одновременно, иначе это может быть воспринято удалённым сервером как сетевая атака. Получите ошибку "Bad gateway" или какую-нибудь ещё. Я ограничился 10-ю одновременными запросами, но при желании можете поэкспериментировать с этой величиной.

В итоге у меня получился макрос, отработавший за 3 минуты с небольшим (03:05)

```vb
Sub parse_v_2()
    Const request_count As Long = 1244
    Const simultaneous_count As Long = 10

    Dim http() As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim user_items As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim user_item As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim startT As Double

    ReDim http(1 To request_count)

    ' создаём сразу все запросы, но не спешим выполнять их
    For j = 1 To request_count
        Set http(j) = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
        Call http(j).Open("GET", "https://rieltor.ua/users/?page=" & CStr(j), True)
    Next j

    Let startT = Now
    Let i = 0

    ' запускаем на выполнение первые 10 запросов
    For j = 1 To simultaneous_count
        Call http(j).send
    Next j

    For j = 1 To request_count
        ' ожидаем выполнения j-го запроса
        Call http(j).WaitForResponse(5000)

        ' запускаем новый запрос взамен "выбывшего"
        If ((j + simultaneous_count) <= request_count) Then _
            Call http(j + simultaneous_count).send

        ' обработка результатов
        If (http(j).Status = 200) Then
            Let html.body.innerHTML = http(j).responseText

            Set user_items = html.getElementsByClassName("user-item")
            For Each user_item In user_items
                Let i = i + 1

                With user_item.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
                    Лист2.Cells(i, 1) = .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
                    Лист2.Cells(i, 2) = .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
                    Лист2.Cells(i, 3) = .getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
                    Лист2.Cells(i, 4) = .getElementsByTagName("div")(5).innerText
                    Лист2.Cells(i, 5) = .getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
                    Лист2.Cells(i, 6) = .getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
                End With
            Next user_item
        Else
            Лист2.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = "Были успешно обработаны " & CStr(j - 1) & " страниц"
            Лист2.Cells(i + 3, 1).Value = "Ошибка при обработке " & CStr(j) & "-й страницы: " & http(j).statusText

            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    For j = 1 To request_count
        Set http(j) = Nothing
    Next j

    Erase http
    Set html = Nothing
    Set user_items = Nothing
    Set user_item = Nothing

    MsgBox "Время выполнения макроса " & Format((Now - startT), "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: Автору останется объединить советы в одном коде )

Comment: Да, стоит попробовать ) Но, мне кажется, заметный профит будет только на слабом железе, где код упрётся в быстродействие процессора (основной поток Excel загрузит одно из ядер полностью, на 100%)

Comment: А почему не работает строка
`Set user_items = html.getElementsByClassName("user-item")` ?
Ошибка 438: Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод.

Comment: Только что запустил у себя этот код - и он отработал без ошибок (Office 2016 для дома и учёбы).
BYFLY, я не могу сказать, в чём у Вас проблема.
Причина может быть в чём угодно... Повторный запуск пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Да, работа с объектами листа медленная, нужно переходить на массивы. Если есть возможность. определить количество строк для записи данных, если нет - задать размерность массива с запасом (`ReDim` в примере - 5000).

При каждом изменении на экране идет его перерисовка. Медленная операция. `Application.ScreenUpdating` - отключить/включить обновление экрана. Это намного ускорит работу макроса, а в паре с массивами - в десятки раз.

Остальное - по мелочам.

Переменные типа `Integer` украдут несколько мгновений, т.к. все равно преобразуются в `Long`. Можно откусить чуток памяти в угоду времени.

Оператор `With` не только делает код более читабельным, но и ускоряет обращение к объекту.

Непонятно применение строковой переменной `strT`. Зачем в нее что-то писать (и на каждом шаге цикла), если она нигде не применяется?

Переменная `d` дублирует переменную `i`, лишняя.

Не забываем освобождать память (`Set переменная = Nothing`). На скорость не повлияет и обычно память сама освобождается по окончании работы макроса, но бывают случаи, когда регистры памяти остаются занятыми. Поэтому правильнее чистить принудительно.

Получится что-то типа такого:

```
Sub parse_kiev2()
    Dim aData()
    Dim http As Object, user_items As Object, titleElem As Object, detailsElem As Object
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, user_item As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim startT  As Double

    startT = Now
    ReDim aData(1 To 5000, 1 To 6)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For j = 1 To 1244
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        With http
            .Open "GET", "https://rieltor.ua/users/?page=" & j & "", False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        Set user_items = html.getElementsByClassName("user-item")
        If j = 1 Then i = 1 Else i = d

        For Each user_item In user_items
            Set titleElem = user_item.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
            i = i + 1

            With titleElem
                aData(i, 1) = .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
                aData(i, 2) = .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
                aData(i, 3) = .getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innerText
                aData(i, 4) = .getElementsByTagName("div")(5).innerText
                aData(i, 5) = .getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
                aData(i, 6) = .getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
            End With
        Next user_item
    Next j

    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Resize(i, 6).Value = aData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Время выполнения макроса " & Format((Now - startT), "hh:mm:ss")
    Set user_items = Nothing: Set http = Nothing
End Sub
```